# iPython/jupyter notebook fails to start "image not found"

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, pyzmq

Trying to start iPython/jupyter notebook crashes giving the following error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/constants.so, 2): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libzmq.3.dylib 
Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/constants.so 
Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tracked down a solution here:

https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/issues/493

Something had gone wrong with the install of pyzmq but uninstalling via macports or pip then reinstalling didn't get rid of the problem files.

Deleting the zmq directories from `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` then reinstalling using pip fixed this.